# My app list on a new phone

Tags: applications

I would like to buy a new phone, and don't want to install my currently used apps one by one on it. Is there a way to automatically restore my apps on the new phone?

Answer (score 1):

Sure is!  When you get your new android phone and sign in with your Google account, it will automatically start to re download your apps!  If you want to root the new phone, and the previous one (the one you own now) was also rooted, you could use titanium backup as well to back up your apps and reinstall the them with all their data on the new device.

Comment: Based on what information this is done? When i look at the play store -> my applications section i see all the apps i have ever used in my life. I certainly don't want all these crap installed on the new one.

Comment: Whenever factory reset my phone (which is practically getting a new one)  apps you previously had on your old device will install onto your new one.  I believe the apps that are not on any of your devices will not be reinstalled.  Im not 100% sure that it doesn't install ALL your old apps because I use Titanium Backup.  If you find its installing everything, you can always hit the cancel button!

Comment: But why the hell play store shows all the apps i ever used? make no sense to me. is there a way to edit my app list?

Comment: Btw is this work the same way when i do a factory reset on the old phone?

Comment: I did the factory reset, and do far my play apps are not restored grrr...

Comment: Do note that this only happens if **Back up my data** was turned on in the old phone's **Backup & reset** settings, and if you answer "yes" when the first-time setup on your new phone asks you if you want to restore.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was, yet no applications are restored

Comment: And now i'm pissed.

Comment: Did you factory reset through the bootloader?